# Library filter not working properly?

Tags: document-library

Hi i have a library where i have filter that x column begins with y and few more filters after that i have added but the library items are not coming properly . What could be the reason? [image: my example]

[image: view]

Comment: When working with multiple list conditions, it's easier to add them one by one and check if they apply correctly after each condition added.

Comment: Correct , the problem is its working in other view with same filters , but not working in this view.

Comment: Did you recreate the view manually? Then i would check for some blank spaces or so in the conditions.

Comment: Actually i want it according to the image.. but the problem is its not happening with the filter, even if i put sorting thats arranging ascending/desc wise. I only want it as first column should come like its in the image. Any idea of oob techniques?

Comment: It's better to break them down and try to group them. Most of the times i have problems with multiple is condition is due to "And" & "Or" overrides each other.

Comment: Yes Correct this or and creates problems. ok will check thanks